# Row selection in a DataGridView

Tags: winforms

In my WinForms project I have a `Form` with a `DataGridView`. When the application loads, the `DataGridView` is filled with data. In my`DataGridView`, `SelectionMode` is set to `FullFowSelect`.

**Question 1:** When the `Form` loads, how can I make it so that no row is selected in the `DataGridView`?

**Question 2:** And after the initial load, how can I program a `Button` to highlight a specific row (for example, the 5th row) in the `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 1):

```
datagridview.Rows[index].Selected = true;
```

in your case to select fifth row

```
datagridview.Rows[4].Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should set **CurrentCell** for the DataGridView

So for your case fifth row should be

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, 4];
```

Comment: Selection mode is fullrowselect and he wants to give selection back color to a row and not a cell

Comment: @Niraj: yes, the above code does that part , the row is selected as required (Did you try your solution didn't work for me)